# How can I place three divs with responsive properties?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I place three divs as in the added image (two horizontally and one vertically) to the bottom of horizontal divs with responsive properties?

[image: Display]

I am using the following CSS:

```
.rightallign{ float: right; }
.leftallign{ float: left; }
```

For the two divs to be horizontal, but it's not working.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "responsive properties"?

Comment: The screen should be responsive in nature

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you would do it with floats.

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
div {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #eee;
}
.half {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.full {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="half">one</div>
<div class="half">two</div>
<div class="full">three</div>
```

You could also use flexbox on the top row and you won't have to specify any sort of width.

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
div {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #eee;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.flex > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="half">one</div>
  <div class="half">two</div>
</div>
<div class="full">three</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

DIVs by default take up 100% of the width of the page. Assuming your two divs have the correct classes `.leftallign` and `.rightallign`, you also need to make sure they only occupy 50% of the width (at max) in order to display next to each other:

```css
.leftallign {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.rightallign {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftallign">1</div>
<div class="rightallign">2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)